# How to list <item name="app:fabSize">[value]</item> in styles.xml?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, floating-action-button

I tried to include the app:fabSize in styles.xml but android studio threw an error

[image]

Is there any way to include the app:fabSize and other app: attributes in styles.xml?

[Here is the code for the style tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GWsa.png)

Comment: without `app:`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When adding Compat attributes in layout.xml one should use previously defined namespace (it doesn't have to be `app` actually, but should be defined in xml via `xmlns:` - for example having `hello` as a namespace is also possible. Anyway `app` is some kind of a standard).

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    xmlns:hello="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    hello:fabSize="mini"/>
```

But in styles.xml to use Compat attributes one shouldn't put anything, but attribute name:

```
<style name="StyleName">
    <item name="fabSize">mini</item>
</style>
```